# Concat query mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
reference - model - category
0001     - NON     - 2
0001     - NON     - 5
0001     - NON     - 12
0001     - SAN     - 2
0001     - SAN     - 5
0001     - SAN     - 12
```

I am looking for this result:

```
reference - model - categories
0001     - NON     - 2,5,12
0001     - SAN     - 2,5,12
```

I tried with concat and group_concat without any result like this. Is this possible in this case?

Comment: Next time, post the failed effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select reference, model, group_concat(category) categories From tableName
 group by reference, model
```